# Preventing Image from being cleared [PYGAME- Python]

Tags: python, pygame

It's extremely painful to redraw each image everytime the screen is cleared.

```
    import pygame
    from pygame.locals import *  
    T = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
    M = pygame.image.load("test.jpg")
    X = 0
    Y = 0
    while True:
       X += 1
       Y += 1
    # Other sprites are here which are also redrawn every time loop runs.
    # Other code is here too, this is just a little part of it to help explain my problem
       T.fill((0,0,0))
       T.blit(M,(X,Y))
       pygame.display.flip()
```

In the above code, I am loading the background image in M Variable, everytime I clear the screen to update the position of my sprites, I also have to redraw the background image which is causing severe FPS drops.

Anyway I can prevent the Background image from being cleared whenever I am using T.fill((0,0,0)) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try to `convert` the background image. Images should usually be converted with `convert` or `convert_alpha` to improve the performance.

```
M = pygame.image.load("test.jpg").convert()
```

Second, if the background image has the size of the screen you can omit the line `T.fill((0,0,0))`, since the background fills the screen anyway.

Third, if the background isn't scrolling and you only need to update some portions of the screen every frame,  you can try to use [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) instead of `pygame.display.flip()`. Pass a single rect or a list of rects to `pygame.display.update` to tell it which parts of the screen should be updated.

I'm not sure if these measures will improve the performance drastically. Pygame is rather slow because it still relies on software rendering.

Sidenote, use descriptive variable names instead of T, M, etc..